# Javascript based content dissapears from sticky sidebar

Tags: javascript

I have a sidebar with a ul list, like so:

```
<div id="sidebar">
<ul>
</ul>
</div>
```

There is no actual html content in the sidebar because the ul list are being populated through a javascript function. So my javascript function fills in the ul list once the page has finished loading.

The problem is that I want to make this sidebar sticky, but the moment I make it sticky, the content inside the ul list dissapears (as if javascript cant recognize my ul list anymore).

What I tried:

- I tried making the sidebar sticky using pure css like "position: sticky"
- I tried using the "Sticksy" script from: https://sticksy.js.org/ The sticksy script works great, but the result is the same: my ul list are no longer being filled in by my javascript function.

As mentioned, it's as if javascript can't find the ul list to add the content to, while the sidebar is sticky. Any advice on how to get around this?

EDIT: (here is the function that ads code to my ul list)

```
var summaryWidgetList = document.querySelector("#sidebar ul");    
function mySummary() {
    var selectionList = document.querySelectorAll("#site-main .product-title");
    selectionList.forEach(selectionItem => {
        var selectionItemTag = document.createElement("li");
        selectionItemTag.innerHTML = selectionItem.textContent;
        summaryWidgetList.appendChild(selectionItemTag);
    })
}
window.addEventListener('load', mySummary);
```

Comment: So what is the code to make it sticky?

Comment: I already gave info on how I made the sidebar sticky, but I added more details to my question

Comment: It's still not enough information. You need to show a complete example ([mcve]), at least the part that doesn't work (adding content with JS.)

Comment: I disagree, the problem is not with the sticky sidebar. I DONT need help making my sidebar sticky, it is already sticky!! I just asked for advice on why javascript content won't display inside a sticky sidebar (there must be reason and I need input from others regarding that issue). Adding more info regarding how I made my sidebar sticky will be pointless because that is not where the problem is (I already gave enough info on how I did that)

Comment: Yes, but I didn't ask for more info about the stickyness part. I asked for the part where you add content with JS. Surely you understand that we can't know why the code doesn't work without seeing it.

Comment: Okay, I will post my function but I highly doubt that there is anything wrong with the function

Answer (score 0):

Well, try to append data to your ul element.
Create ID for ul element:

```
<ul id="list">
</ul>
```

Now append the <li> elements in your desired way to "list" element.
F.ex. using vanilla JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += "<li> filled </li>"
```

I created a very simple example:
https://playcode.io/695917/